# How do I use the output of a command for a process within a loop in Bash?

Tags: shell-script

I'm tring to obtain the format info of a bunch of media files in a directory. The script I have goes through each file, mentions what format its in (if it's a media file) and then exits.

What I really wanted to do was to run a specific command if the output matched a certain value. here's the code I have:

```
for file in ./*
do
    ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 "$file" 
done
```

Here's a sample output I get when I run it in a folder with 10 files and 1 directory:

```
vorbis
aac
opus
vorbis
mp3
opus
mp3
./file1.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
./Soundcloud: Is a directory
mp3
./media_bash_file.sh: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Ideally, what I'm trying to do is once the ffprobe command runs I want to go

```
if ffprobe_output = "vorbis" then run x command ELSE ...
```

and so on. I've tried what's mentioned in various blog posts about using

```
var=$(insert_ffprobe_command_here)
```

at the very start of the batch file but I can't seem to get it to work properly, it usually results in an error like:

```
"Argument './Mediafile_X' provided as input filename, but './Mediafile_Y' was already specified.
```

I only have gotten as far as the first snippet of code I made.

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in ./*
do
    output=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 "$file")
    if [ "$output" = "vorbis" ];then ......
    else ....
    fi
done
```